# Error en arreglo de estructura usando funciones

Tags: c

Me marca el siguiente error

> 44    33  C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\ss.cpp  [Error] could not convert '(ALUMNO*)(& NUEVO)' from 'ALUMNO*' to 'ALUMNO'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ALUMNO{
    char nombre[30];
    char edad[2];
    char sexo[10];
    char calle[15];
    char numero[10];
    char colonia[15];
    char telefono[10];  
    int carrera;
    int id;
}NUEVO;

int contInd=0;
int contAdm=0;
int contPsi=0;
int ContGen=0;

void agregarAlumno(ALUMNO);
void imprimeAlumnos(ALUMNO);
void impNumeros();

int main(){
    struct ALUMNO NUEVO[9];

    int op;
    do{
        //system("cls");
        printf("***MENU DE ESCUELA***\n\n");
        printf("1.- Agregar alumno.\n");
        printf("2.- Imprimir lista de alumnos.\n");
        printf("3.- Imprimir cifras de las carreras.\n");
        printf("4.- Salir.\n\n");
        printf("Seleccione su opcion: ");
        scanf("%d", &op);

        //system("cls");

        switch(op) {
            case 1:
                agregarAlumno(NUEVO);
            break;

            case 2:
                imprimeAlumnos(NUEVO);
            break;

            case 3:
                impNumeros();
            break;

            case 4:
                return 0;
            break;

            default:
                printf("Opcion invalida! ");
            break;
        }
    }while(op!=4);

        //system("Pause");

}


void agregarAlumno(struct ALUMNO NUEVO[]) {
    int indexCar;

    for (int x=0;x<=9;x++){
    printf("***AGREGAR NUEVO USUARIO***\n\n");
    printf("\n0 = Ingenieria Industrial \n1 = Administracion \n2 = Psicologia\n ");
    printf("\n\nIngresa el ID de la carrera al que ingresara: ");
    scanf("%d", &indexCar);
    NUEVO[x].carrera=indexCar;

    while(indexCar < 0 || indexCar-1 >= 2){
       printf("\nNo existe ninguna carrera con ese id!");
       printf("\n0 = Ingenieria Industrial \n1 = Administracion \n2 = Psicologia\n ");
       printf("\n\nIngresa el ID de la carrera al que ingresara: ");
       scanf("%d", &indexCar);
    }

    fflush(stdin);

    if  (NUEVO[x].carrera==0) 
     {contInd++;
      ContGen++;
     }
    if  (NUEVO[x].carrera==1) 
     {contAdm++;
      ContGen++;
     }

    if  (NUEVO[x].carrera==2) 
     {contPsi++;
      ContGen++;
     }

        fflush(stdin);

        printf("\nIngresa su nombre: ");
        //gets(NUEVO[c].nombre);
        //scanf( "%s", &NUEVO[c].nombre);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", &NUEVO[x].nombre);

    /*  printf("\nIngresa su edad: ");
        gets(NUEVO[c].edad);

        printf("\nIngresa su sexo (hombre/mujer): ");
        gets(NUEVO[c].sexo);

        printf("\nInformacion de domicilio: ");
        printf("\nIngresa su calle: ");
        gets(NUEVO[c].calle);
        //scanf( "%s", NUEVO[c].calle);
        printf("\nIngresa su numero: ");
        gets(NUEVO[c].numero);      
        printf("\nIngresa su colonia: ");
        gets(NUEVO[c].colonia);
        printf("\nIngresa su Numero telefonco: ");
        gets(NUEVO[c].telefono);
    */   
        NUEVO[x].id=(x+1);
         printf("\nAlumno agregado!\n\n");
    }

}




void imprimeAlumnos(struct ALUMNO NUEVO[]){
//void imprimeAlumnos(){    
    int i=0;
    //system("cls");
    if (NUEVO[i].id>0){

        for(i;i<=ContGen;i++){
            printf("Alumno Numero %d \n",i);
            printf("Nombre: %s \n",NUEVO[i].nombre);
/*          printf("Edad: %s \n",NUEVO[i].edad);
            printf("Sexo: %s \n",NUEVO[i].sexo);
            printf("Direccion: ");
            printf("calle: %s ",NUEVO[i].calle);
            printf("calle: %s ",NUEVO[i].numero);
            printf("numero: %s \n",NUEVO[i].colonia);
            printf("Telefono: %s \n",NUEVO[i].telefono);
            printf("Carrera: %s \n",NUEVO[i].carrera);
*/          printf("\n\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("\n No hay registros\n\n");
    }

}


void impNumeros(){
    printf("El numero de alumnos en Ing Industrial es:\t %d\n",contInd);
    printf("El numero de alumnos en Adm de Empresases:\t %d\n",contAdm);
    printf("El numero de alumnos en Psicologia es: \t %d\n",contPsi);
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

**No uses variables globales**

Para más información consulta esta otra pregunta:

[¿Por qué usar variables globales suele ser una mala idea?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/195000/463)

**Cuidado que estás compilando en C++**

El compilador que estás usando es de C++, si no fuese así el programa daría error en estas líneas:

```
void agregarAlumno(ALUMNO);
void imprimeAlumnos(ALUMNO);
```

Y el motivo es que `ALUMNO` como tal no es nada en C, tienes que añadir `struct`:

```
void agregarAlumno(struct ALUMNO);
void imprimeAlumnos(struct ALUMNO);
```

o usar `typedef` para crear un alias y entonces ahorrarte el `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
    char nombre[30];
    char edad[2];
    char sexo[10];
    char calle[15];
    char numero[10];
    char colonia[15];
    char telefono[10];  
    int carrera;
    int id;
}ALUMNO;

void agregarAlumno(ALUMNO);
void imprimeAlumnos(ALUMNO);
```

**El error**

El mensaje de error es bastante claro. Estás intentando pasar un puntero a una función que no acepta punteros sino variables por valor.

El problema se empaña un poco porque, como has declarado variables globales, tienes un solapamiento de variables:

```
struct ALUMNO{
    char nombre[30];
    char edad[2];
    char sexo[10];
    char calle[15];
    char numero[10];
    char colonia[15];
    char telefono[10];  
    int carrera;
    int id;
}NUEVO; // <<--- Primera declaracion de NUEVO

int contInd=0;
int contAdm=0;
int contPsi=0;
int ContGen=0;

void agregarAlumno(ALUMNO);
void imprimeAlumnos(ALUMNO);
void impNumeros();

int main(){
    struct ALUMNO NUEVO[9]; // <<--- Segunda declaracion de NUEVO
```

El caso es que la variable que te afecta dentro de `main` es la segunda, que si te fijas es un array de 9 elementos. Sin embargo, la función requiere una estructura simple:

```
void agregarAlumno(ALUMNO);
void imprimeAlumnos(ALUMNO);
```

La solución es modificar estas funciones para que acepten un array:

```
void agregarAlumno(ALUMNO[]);
void imprimeAlumnos(ALUMNO[]);
```

Además así conseguirás que dichas declaraciones coincidan con sus respectivas implementaciones:

```
void agregarAlumno(struct ALUMNO NUEVO[]) {
//                                    ^^
    int indexCar;
    // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay una mezcla de tipos objetos declarados y usados que es lo que en resumen te está generando el problema.

En concreto, en tu linea 21 declaras que la función **agregarAlumno** recibe un objeto (no un array) de tipo struct ALUMNO.

```
void agregarAlumno(ALUMNO); <-- Declarado como estructura simple
```

Luego en la línea 44, como bien dice el error (***44*** 33 C:\Users\Miguel\Desktop\ss.cpp [Error] could not convert '(ALUMNO*)(& NUEVO)' from 'ALUMNO*' to 'ALUMNO') indica que quieres pasarle un array de estructuras ALUMNO.

```
agregarAlumno(NUEVO);
```

Por ultimo, en la implementación de la función en la linea 136, cambias la declaración para indicarle que reciba un array:

```
void imprimeAlumnos(struct ALUMNO NUEVO[]){ // <-- Implementado como Array
```

La solución al problema es sencilla, la función debe estar declarada e implementada para poder recibir un array de estructuras. Debes corroborar cuando implementes este tipo de funciones que ambas partes sean iguales ya que el compilador controla el código según lo declarado inicialmente antes de llegar a revisar lo implementado.

Te paso tu código corregido para que puedas probar y verificar esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ALUMNO{
    char nombre[30];
    char edad[2];
    char sexo[10];
    char calle[15];
    char numero[10];
    char colonia[15];
    char telefono[10];  
    int carrera;
    int id;
};

int contInd=0;
int contAdm=0;
int contPsi=0;
int ContGen=0;

void agregarAlumno(struct ALUMNO []);
void imprimeAlumnos(struct ALUMNO []);
void impNumeros();

int main(){
    struct ALUMNO NUEVO[9];

    int op;
    do{
        //system("cls");
        printf("***MENU DE ESCUELA***\n\n");
        printf("1.- Agregar alumno.\n");
        printf("2.- Imprimir lista de alumnos.\n");
        printf("3.- Imprimir cifras de las carreras.\n");
        printf("4.- Salir.\n\n");
        printf("Seleccione su opcion: ");
        scanf("%d", &op);

        //system("cls");

        switch(op) {
            case 1:
                agregarAlumno(NUEVO);
            break;

            case 2:
                imprimeAlumnos(NUEVO);
            break;

            case 3:
                impNumeros();
            break;

            case 4:
                return 0;
            break;

            default:
                printf("Opcion invalida! ");
            break;
        }
    }while(op!=4);

        //system("Pause");

}


void agregarAlumno(struct ALUMNO NUEVO[]) {
    int indexCar;

    for (int x=0;x<9;x++){ // Corregí el rango ya que va de 0 a 8 (ya que son 9 valores los del array)
    printf("***AGREGAR NUEVO USUARIO***\n\n");
    printf("\n0 = Ingenieria Industrial \n1 = Administracion \n2 = Psicologia\n ");
    printf("\n\nIngresa el ID de la carrera al que ingresara: ");
    scanf("%d", &indexCar);
    NUEVO[x].carrera=indexCar;

    while(indexCar < 0 || indexCar-1 >= 2){
    printf("\nNo existe ninguna carrera con ese id!");
    printf("\n0 = Ingenieria Industrial \n1 = Administracion \n2 = Psicologia\n ");
    printf("\n\nIngresa el ID de la carrera al que ingresara: ");
    scanf("%d", &indexCar);
    }

    fflush(stdin);

    if  (NUEVO[x].carrera==0) 
    {contInd++;
    ContGen++;
    }
    if  (NUEVO[x].carrera==1) 
    {contAdm++;
    ContGen++;
    }

    if  (NUEVO[x].carrera==2) 
    {contPsi++;
    ContGen++;
    }

        fflush(stdin);

        printf("\nIngresa su nombre: ");
        //gets(NUEVO[c].nombre);
        //scanf( "%s", &NUEVO[c].nombre);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", NUEVO[x].nombre);

    /*  printf("\nIngresa su edad: ");
        gets(NUEVO[c].edad);

        printf("\nIngresa su sexo (hombre/mujer): ");
        gets(NUEVO[c].sexo);

        printf("\nInformacion de domicilio: ");
        printf("\nIngresa su calle: ");
        gets(NUEVO[c].calle);
        //scanf( "%s", NUEVO[c].calle);
        printf("\nIngresa su numero: ");
        gets(NUEVO[c].numero);      
        printf("\nIngresa su colonia: ");
        gets(NUEVO[c].colonia);
        printf("\nIngresa su Numero telefonco: ");
        gets(NUEVO[c].telefono);
    */   
        NUEVO[x].id=(x+1);
        printf("\nAlumno agregado!\n\n");
    }

}




void imprimeAlumnos(struct ALUMNO NUEVO[]){
//void imprimeAlumnos(){    
    int i=0;
    //system("cls");
    if (NUEVO[i].id>0){

        for(i;i<=ContGen;i++){
            printf("Alumno Numero %d \n",i);
            printf("Nombre: %s \n",NUEVO[i].nombre);
/*          printf("Edad: %s \n",NUEVO[i].edad);
            printf("Sexo: %s \n",NUEVO[i].sexo);
            printf("Direccion: ");
            printf("calle: %s ",NUEVO[i].calle);
            printf("calle: %s ",NUEVO[i].numero);
            printf("numero: %s \n",NUEVO[i].colonia);
            printf("Telefono: %s \n",NUEVO[i].telefono);
            printf("Carrera: %s \n",NUEVO[i].carrera);
*/          printf("\n\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("\n No hay registros\n\n");
    }

}


void impNumeros(){
    printf("El numero de alumnos en Ing Industrial es:\t %d\n",contInd);
    printf("El numero de alumnos en Adm de Empresases:\t %d\n",contAdm);
    printf("El numero de alumnos en Psicologia es: \t %d\n",contPsi);
}
```

Hay cosas de buenas practicas a ajustar pero prefiero dejarte claro este punto de lo consultado puntualmente sobre tu implementación para que afiances ese conocimiento. Espero te sirva. Saludos!